# Python - Updating value in one dictionary is updating value in all dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries called `lod`. All dictionaries have the same keys but different values. I am trying to update one specific value in the list of values for the same key in all the dictionaries.

I am attempting to do it with the following for loop:

```
for i in range(len(lod)):
    a=lod[i][key][:]
    a[p]=a[p]+lov[i]
    lod[i][key]=a
```

What's happening is each is each dictionary is getting updated `len(lod)` times so `lod[0][key][p]` is supposed to have `lov[0]` added to it but instead it is getting `lov[0]+lov[1]+....` added to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I declared the list of dicts:

```
lod = [{} for _ in range(len(dataul))]
for j in range(len(dataul)):
    for i in datakl:
        rrdict[str.split(i,',')[0]]=list(str.split(i,',')[1:len(str.split(i,','))])
    lod[j]=rrdict
```

Comment: Please post more complete code. What is datakl? How is rrdict initialized? Are you really sure, you want to index lov[i] in the first code fragment? Some data sample would also improve the quality of the question a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in how you created the list of dictionaries. You probably did something like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{}] * 20
```

That's actually the *same* `dict` 20 times. Try doing something like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{} for _ in range(20)]
```

Without seeing how you actually created it, this is only an example solution to an example problem.

To know for sure, print this:

```
[id(x) for x in list_of_dicts]
```

If you defined it in the `* 20` method, the `id` is the same for each `dict`. In the list comprehension method, the `id` is unique.

Comment: yes ok thanks for the quick response. each of my ids are the same. However, I tried declaring the list_of_dicts in the way you suggested and I still have identical dicts.

Answer (score 1):

This it where the trouble starts: `lod[j] = rrdict`. `lod` itself is created properly with different dictionaries. Unfortunately, afterwards any references to the original dictionaries in the list get overwritten with a reference to `rrdict`. So in the end, the list contains only references to one single dictionary. Here is some more pythonic and readable way to solve your problem:

```
lod = [{} for _ in range(len(dataul))]
for rrdict in lod:
    for line in datakl:
        splt = line.split(',')
        rrdict[splt[0]] = splt[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the list of dictionaries correctly, as per other answer.
However, when you are updating individual dictionaries, you completely overwrite the list.
Removing noise from your code snippet:

```
lod = [{} for _ in range(whatever)]

for j in range(whatever):
    # rrdict = lod[j] # Uncomment this as a possible fix.
    for i in range(whatever):
        rrdict[somekey] = somevalue
    lod[j] = rrdict
```

Assignment on the last line throws away the empty dict that was in lod[j] and inserts a reference to the object represented by rrdict.
Not sure what your code does, but see a commented-out line - it might be the fix you are looking for.