# How to create a list containing N Lists each containing N distinct dictionaries using comprehension syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    oneCounts = [[{'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0}] * N for i in range(0,N)]     
    oneCounts[0][1]['t'] = 3
```

In the above code setting key value on a specific dictionary causes all dictionaries in the same list to get their t key values get set to the same value. This is unexpected to me. What am I missing?

Comment: `[{'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0}] * N` gives you a list of `N` references to the same dictionary object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Updating value in one dictionary is updating value in all dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518486/python-updating-value-in-one-dictionary-is-updating-value-in-all-dictionaries)

Comment: @glibdud How can I make it so that I get N references to separate dictionaries?

Comment: @neo Use a (nested) comprehension, as in schwobaseggl's answer.

Comment: I reverted the edit to the body (but kept the improved title). Without the example it's more difficult to parse what you're actually looking for. But go ahead and put it back if you prefer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line to

```
oneCounts = [[{'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0} for _ in range(N)] for i in range(0, N)] 
# oneCounts = [[{'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0} for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]
```

in order to create **independent** dictionaries.

`[x] * n` creates a list of n references to the **same** object `x`. You should only use that syntax when `x` is of an immutable type, e.g. `int`.

Comment: this creates only one dictionary in the list. That's not what I want.

Comment: No, it creates `N` lists of `N` dicts each. Have you tried it?

Comment: What I want is a list with N Lists and each list containing N separate dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the unexpected result is you are calling the constructor just once and then using the same object N times. So, in effect, you are appending the same object N times to **oneCounts** because the lists containing the dictionaries have the same reference.

Try out the following:

```
oneCounts = []
for i in range(N):
    oneCounts.append([{'l':0,'r':0,'t':0,'b':0} for j in range(N)])
```

Here, **oneCounts**  is a list containing N Lists and each list contains N separate dictionaries.

edit : I just noticed the answer given by user 'schwobaseggl'. It does the same thing as my code, but with less typing. I personally like that answer better.